# android: how to not overlay views with the navigation bar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, navigationbar

im having a problem with my layout. i've implemented a tab bar layout with a view pager in an activity, and i've been researching for answers but no luck to solve it well my problem is that my tab bars has an element  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. at first it wasn't showing (image below)
[tab bar not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP40W.jpg)

and added an element `android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"` to check if it really overlays at the navigation bar and it seems that it does. [tab bar shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH4zs.jpg)

can someone help me with this? i think my problem is with the styles. 
here is my styles:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.MyCureTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/font_darker_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_gray</item>
</style><style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>


<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarThemeDark"
    parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/font_gray</item>
</style>
```

EDITED :

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
    android:background="@color/font_gray"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    app:tabGravity="center"/>

<com.mycurepatient.android.widgets.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your XML layout.

Comment: @krislarson added xml

Comment: Hmmm... Don't see anything obviously wrong,  Does your CustomViewPager override `onMeasure()` or `onLayout`?

Comment: no i haven't and if i should can you give me some advice?

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need those overrides, I just saw that you had a custom class, so it might have done its sizing differently.  The only thing I can suggest at this point would be to take out your horizontal line view and see if it makes a difference, or maybe put your widgets in a different order.  Technically your view pager should be above the horizontal line in order for you to see that line.

Comment: i only used that custom class to add `setPagingEnabled` but even though i used the android.support.v4.view.ViewPager nothing changes. that's why i concluded that there's something wrong with my styles. dont you think i miss something with the styles? btw many thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's the styles because you don't specify `style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"` on the tabs and the other styling is pretty much just colors.

Comment: @krislarson i solved it by removing `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`

Comment: Okay, wait a second... if this layout is included into an activity layout, please post that XML, I think I might know what your problem is.  You might be able to fix this and keep the toolbar scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by removing `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`